# How to predict custom value from trained model?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

Im pretty new to python understanding the ML architecture.

I designed a scenario, trained my model and my test results are working as expected. 
I have around 5 rows in my test data
My question is..if i want to test on single record and get prediction how can i do that? 
I get below error when i test with single record

Below is my code sample and error. Please help

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dataset = pd.read_csv('MLData2.csv')
# Data: 
#A  1   1
#A  1   1
#A  1   1
#A  2   1
#A  2   1
#B  3   3
#B  3   3
#B  3   3
#B  4   3
#B  5   3
#C  4   4
#C  1   4
#C  2   4
#C  3   4

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values

y = dataset.iloc[:,2].values


#Encode data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0])
X[:,1] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,1])
#onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = "all")
#X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

#labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
#y = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(y)
#onehotencoder_y = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = "all")
#y = np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))
#y = onehotencoder_y.fit_transform(y).toarray()

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 
0.2, random_state = 42)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", random_state 
= 42)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
sTest = np.reshape([0,3], (-1,1))

#I want to test model for inputs C 3, which should return 4. How to 
test that?
y_pred1 = classifier.predict(sTest)
```

Below is the error received

`ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 2 and input n_features is 1`

To be short , my output should always be 1 for A, 3 for B, 4 for C (in my scenario)

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 2 and input n_features is 1
```

That means your input to the model has a different shape than expected.

Your model expect 2D samples, that is a numpy array of shape `(n_samples, n_features)` with `n_features=2`. In your case you want to test on a single sample, so `n_samples=1`. You need to pass a `np.array` with shape `(1, 2)`.
Try:

`sTest = np.reshape([0,3], (1, -1))`